# How to develop a sync pipeline in azure data factory? and also how to use trigger for that and in the screenshot ref and elr are table names

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

> quote in the picture ref and elr are table names in sql database

> quote
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFtQb.png

Comment: Please follow this guideline to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a good tutorial if you are starting out with Azure Data Factory by Catherine Wilhemsen: https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/series/beginners-guide-azure-data-factory/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.